# How to apply jquery datepicker on duplicate id's in same form?

Tags: jquery

I have a complex code where I need to clone  same tables on dynamic call and have to apply date picker on them.The problem is that there will be duplicate id's on which I am willing to apply date picker.So, when I apply date picker,it comes and I can select only current date using Enter key.But,when I use mouse it throws error like "TypeError: f is undefined" .Please provide the solution.Thank you

Comment: You must not have duplicate IDs. IDs are unique by definition.

Answer (score 2):

I had same problem. I checked inside renderer html using firebug and I found that my html containing other element with same id than datepicker. Remove that id solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Duplicate IDs aren't valid html. Make them unique, or remove them and use a shared css class.

Answer (score 0):

Duplicate IDs are not valid HTML markup.  When you search for an element by ID, it will only find the first match and return it.   You are better off adding a class to each of the elements and then doing a query on that class to apply the date picker.

Answer (score 0):

you should never have duplicate ids on a form Its not valid html. Instead put a name attribute and select them all using $('input[]') or by css class $('.mycssclass')